# Need to POST data to an API during course completion in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I have a separate server along with my Moodle DB, which holds all user-course data. In some of my plug-ins (type: block) I fetch details from API (which operates with the other server) and display in blocks.
My requirement is to customize the code of course completion activity by an user, e.g. if user launches a course, **I need to POST some data** (for example: timestamp, course completion % etc.) to the API **when user closes the course after completing or without completing the course**.
I guess I need to modify the file *"mod/scorm/locallib.php"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the events in Moodle.

Have a look at this answer- [Email moodle user data after registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416746/email-moodle-user-data-after-registration)

but replace user_created with course_completed.