# After registration hook in moodle

Tags: plugins, hook, moodle

I want to add custom function after new user register in site. I need to create new plugin for that but i don't know about moodle hooks. What type of hook will call after user registration.

Answer (score 2):

The event '\core\event\user_created' is fired when a new user account is created. You can write a plugin to handle that event.

You can declare that your plugin wants to handle that event by adding a db/events.php file within your plugin - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2#Event_observers for more details.

Comment: thank you for reply. i followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416746/email-moodle-user-data-after-registration and done my self.